# Customized message for endpoints not found in WCF Rest Service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, endpoints, wcf-endpoint

I am using WCF to create a ReSTful service. Say my OperationContract is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 UriTemplate = "GetItemList/{token}/{value}"
)]
Stream GetItemList(string token);
```

So when I call http://example.com/Service1.svc/GetItemList/myToken/myValue the service will be called.

Now I want to write a default method saying something link, 'No Method/End point exists', wen the user calls 
     http://example.com/Service1.svc/GetItemList/myToken/ or 
     http://example.com/Service1.svc/GetItemList/myValue/ or
     http://example.com/Service1.svc/GetItemList/

How can I implement that in my code?

Right now what I'm doing is like:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
   UriTemplate = "GetItemList/"
 )]
 string ValidateItemList();

 [OperationContract]
 [WebGet(
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
   UriTemplate = "GetItemList/{Val1}"
 )]
 string ValidateItemList(string Val1);
```

And in the function, I just return a string saying "No method Exists".

Is there a better way? Can I customize error messages, for urls that are directed to my service? Say, a common message for all non existing url requests, that are directed to my service?

Comment: I also would love an answer to this, I posted a similar question, and was pointed to the dispatcher component, but dispatchers are associcated with endpoints, and the whole point is that svc hosts do not create any endpoints for requests that do not specifically match the given uri template

Comment: @NathanTregillus, Yes. thats true. What I wanted was something like Finally in Try-Catch. A default function which will execute when the request don't match any URI. Seems like, there isn't any option for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any feasible solution for my above problem. But I have found an alternate option. With VS 2012, Microsoft has released ASP.NET Web API. Which, they say, is the next version of WCF Rest. So in thet, you could handle these situations very easily. We can use the routing method in it.

Anyone intrested for that solution, can look into this post for a head start: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the architecture of WCF attempts to abstract the low level components of any protocol (in this case http) away so you don't have to worry about these types of details. Unfortunate;y, that engine does not expose a nice way to handle the request's that the engine cannot route correctly.

In this case, the URI cannot be "dispatched" to the correct contract implementing class. the engine has these wonderful components called, wait for it, Dispatchers, which can be customized within the wcf framework, either by configuration or programmatically. The problem is that they are a serious pain to implement. I have implemented the unexpected message dispatcher in my answer to another question, listed below:

[Handling Invalid URI passed to a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193356/handling-invalid-uri-passed-to-a-wcf-service/11570181#11570181)

Let me know if you need any further information!